# Where are my .pst files, for Outlook 2013?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/934293/269574) introduced another problem with Outlook:  my computer lacks .pst files.

1. 4 of 5 email accounts are @outlook.com, and are listed as 'Exchange ActiveSync' under 'Type'. But these 4 are all personal accounts; they don't concern any servers or administrators.
   1 is my work email, and is listed as 'IMAP/SMTP'.
2. I confirm my selection to view all hidden files and folders.
3. I tried searching for .pst files with Windows Explorer, but nothing emerged.
4. I assume that Outlook ought have already created and then automatically updated .PSTs:

> [[Source:]](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/create-pst-file-for-outlook-2013/) Although the default install of Outlook creates a .PST file [...]

5. The following quote discusses 3 methods. 6 simply led me to the same folder cited in 8, which contains only .ost files. No .pst files appear.

7 led me to `F:\Documents\Outlook Files`, but this was empty.

> [[Source:]](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Introduction-to-Outlook-Data-Files-pst-and-ost--222eaf92-a995-45d9-bde2-f331f60e2790?ui=en-US&rs=en-IN&ad=IN) The fastest way to open the folder where your Outlook Data File (.pst and .ost) is saved is to do the following:
>
> [**6.**] I. In Outlook, click the File tab.
>   II. Click Account Settings, and then click Account Settings.
>   III. On the Data Files tab, click an entry, and then click Open Folder Location.
>
> [**7.**] Outlook Data Files (.pst) created by using Outlook 2013 are saved on your computer in the Documents\Outlook Files folder.
>
> [**8.**] If you upgraded to Outlook 2013 on a computer that already had data files that were created in Microsoft Office Outlook 2007 or earlier, these files are saved in a different location in a hidden folder at drive:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook.

Comment: If you ARE using a Exchange account (as DavidPostill asks) you'll be looking for .ost files instead of .pst files.

Comment: @DavidPostill I didn't realise this before, but yes, 4 of 5 email accounts are labelled as 'Exchange ActiveSync' as the 'type'.

Comment: @ssnobody I am, and updated my OP above.

Comment: If you want to backup your files but have OST instead of PST you can either use one of the third party tools for opening OST files (not recommended) or you can use Outlook's Export functionality to export the email accounts to an actual PST. See http://www.cumc.columbia.edu/it/howto/email/exp13.html

Comment: IMAP isn't going to generate a pst file neither is active sync.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What are .ost and.pst files?

> Outlook Data Files (.ost) are used when you have an Exchange account and want to work offline or use or use the default Cached Exchange Mode. This type of data file is also used for accounts that you set up with the Outlook Connector for Outlook.com (formerly Hotmail). Outlook Data Files (.ost) are always copies of items that are saved on a mail server and don’t have to be backed up like Outlook Data Files (.pst).

Source [Introduction to Outlook Data Files (.pst and .ost)](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Introduction-to-Outlook-Data-Files-pst-and-ost--6d4197ec-1304-4b81-a17d-66d4eef30b78?ui=en-US&rs=en-ZA&ad=ZA)

---

#### My computer seems to lack .pst files.

> "4 (of 5) email accounts are @outlook.com, and are listed as 'Exchange ActiveSync', under 'Type'. However, these 4 are all personal accounts on my personal computer. They don't concern any servers or administrators.
> 1 (of the 5) is my work email, and is listed as 'IMAP/SMTP'."

This confirms that your email is using Microsoft Exchange (in the case of your work IMAP/SMTP account). The `.ost` files are from accounts that you have set up with the Outlook Connector for Outlook.com (formerly Hotmail).

> Outlook Data Files (.ost) are always copies of items that are saved on a mail server and don’t have to be backed up like Outlook Data Files (.pst).

The adminstrator of your work Exchange Server (in the case of your work IMAP/SMTP account) should be responsible for backing up the server (and your emails).

You might like to confirm with them that backups are actually taking place.

For the other email accounts @outlook.com then Microsoft is the administrator of 'your email server'

---

#### Do I need to backup an .ost file?

> Some accounts use an offline Outlook Data File (.ost). This is a synchronized copy of the messages saved on a server and that can be accessed from multiple devices and applications such as Outlook. These accounts include IMAP, Microsoft Exchange Server, and Outlook.com accounts.
>
> Offline Outlook Data Files are saved in
>
> `drive:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook`.
>
> It isn’t necessary to back up an offline Outlook Data File (.ost) as it is a copy of the information on the server. If you set up the account again or on another computer or device, a synchronized copy of your messages are downloaded from the server.

Source [Create an Outlook Data File (.pst) to save your information](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-Outlook-Data-File-pst-to-save-your-information-24e6eafe-5700-4994-99e6-1783f556bbd2)

---

#### But I really want to backup these 4 .OST accounts

In this case you might like to backup the local `.ost` files using your normal backup program (or trust Microsoft not to mess up your accounts)

You can also **export** your mail as a `.pst` file by following the instructions in [Exporting and Importing Mailbox Content in Outlook 2013](http://www.cumc.columbia.edu/it/howto/email/exp13.html).

The `.pst` file can then also be backed up using your normal backup program.

The advantage of using a `.pst` file is you can then import all of your email to another computer running Outlook.

Note:

If you access your email account from multiple computers or devices, it’s important to know that when messages are **moved** to an Outlook Data File (.pst) they are available only on the computer where the file is saved.

---

#### **Clarifications as per your comments**.

> You wrote Microsoft Exchange (in the case of your work IMAP/SMTP account). Does this mean a Microsoft Exchange account that also runs on IMAP/SMTP?

Microsoft Exchange can be configured to support IMAP/SMTP. It could also be some other mail server that supports IMAP/SMTP. Only your work IT department can answer this question.

> How do I backup .ost files? Do I just copy and paste them onto backup storage (ie an USB, external hard drive)?

You can copy and paste but it is better to use a [scheduled windows backup](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/backup-and-restore).

> It’s important to know that when messages are moved to an Outlook Data File (.pst) : How can email messages be moved to a .pst?

Email messages will be moved if you [create a local archive](http://How%20to%20Change%20Mail%20to%20PST%20in%20Outlook), and drag and drop emails into the local archive.

You can configure Outlook to **automatically** move your emails to the local `pst` file if you wish. See [How to Automatically Move Mails From Outlook to PST](http://classroom.synonym.com/automatically-move-mails-outlook-pst-19932.html).

Note:

If you **export** your mail from `.ost` to `.pst` you are creating a copy of your email **not** moving it.

---

#### Further reading

- [Archive or back up your mailbox](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Archive-or-back-up-your-mailbox-456b06b3-77da-48ef-8a04-6c31a92f0782?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB) (video)
- [Create and use Personal Folders (Outlook Data Files)](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Create-and-use-Personal-Folders-Outlook-Data-Files--cc784f7c-70c4-495d-bcbf-f3fcb679651f?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB) (video)
- [Outlook 2013 training courses, videos and tutorials](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Outlook-2013-training-courses-videos-and-tutorials-f83e8e60-0bab-47eb-8f6e-c2ecb73124d8)

Comment: You create a local archive follow the directions in the outlook help, then drag and drop the emails, into the local archive within outlook

Comment: +1. Thank you effusively for your support. I hope for others' upvoting of your supernal answer.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Outlook 2013 creates OST file by default. So if you're using Outlook 2013, there would be no PST file. Why don't you read this article https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2752583

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! While your answer might technically right we prefer to have fuller more complete answers. Please take a look at the [tour] to see how things work here. In the mean time could you [edit] your answer to include the relevant sections of the KB article?

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.